# Is it possible to configure API Management through customization UI (calling REST API)?

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

I want to build an UI by myself to configure on APIM like create subscription key, create user or add APIs to product. How can we implement in this approach ? Please share me reference documentation mention about this

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [ARM management rest Apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/) if users have to authenticates against Azure AD

**OR** use the [direct management Apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/api-management-rest) if you want to do it with SAS token